# How to backup SQL Server database using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I am trying to backup a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, name of the database is `test`.

I am using the following PowerShell script but I get an error message that database does not exist, but I can see the `test` database and tables and I can query it.

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance testpc-001\SQLEXPRESS -Database test -BackupAction   
Database
```

and if I try an edit the above script using

```
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss
$dbname = 'test'
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance SQLEXPRESS -Database $dbname -BackupFile   
"C:\DBbackups\$($dbname)_db_$($dt).bak"
```

I am getting an error failed to connect to `SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: can some one help on this please

Comment: Are you using SQL Authentication or Windows Authentication for the connection?

Comment: i am using windows authentication

Comment: I see connection parameters `ServerInstance` and `Database`.  You would also need to indicate that you're using Windows Authentication for you connection.  I don't see that anywhere.  For instance, an ODBC connection string would include "Trusted_Connection=yes;" to indicate Windows Authentication.

Comment: i am not sure how to do that , can you please try to modify my script , really appreciated

Comment: you don't need to specify that you are using windows auth as that is assumed by powershell if you don't specify any other creds.  Can you post the exact error message from your first script as that should be all you need, your second script is wrong as you haven't specified a server name (just the instance) so it will never connect

Answer (score 7):

```
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss
$dbname = 'test'
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance testpc-001\SQLEXPRESS  -Database $dbname -BackupFile   
"C:\DBbackups\$($dbname)_db_$($date).bak"
```

there was a typo in the -ServerInstance parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy');
$database1 = "Path\to\folder" + $datetime + ".bak";

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("password", $password)

Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "SERVER ADDRESS" -Credential $Cred -Database Dummy_Bkp -Initialize -BackupFile $database1;

start-sleep -Seconds 20
```